# Log differentiation of aggregate production function

Tags: macroeconomics, production-function, aggregate-production

Suppose we have an aggregate production function $Y = A F(K, L)$. I'm following some slides which then states that we if log differentiate we get the following:
$\frac{\dot{Y}}{Y} = \frac{\dot{A}}{A} + \frac{F_{K}' \dot{K}}{F K} + \frac{F_{L}' \dot{L}}{F L}$. 
Where the dot notation $\dot{Y}$ is the differential of Y wrt. t. I've tried to using eulers theorem about homogen functions so that we can write $Y = F_{k}'K + F_{L}'L$, but I can't see where I would get the $\frac{\dot{K}}{K}$ terms.

Can anyone guide me? Please ask for more information if i'm not clear enough, thanks!

**EDIT:**
I wrote the formula wrong... its $\frac{\dot{Y}}{Y} = \frac{\dot{A}}{A} + \frac{F_{K}' K \dot{K}}{F K} + \frac{F_{L}' L \dot{L}}{F L}$

Comment: This seems straightforward: have you tried differentiating w.r.t. $t$ and then dividing by $Y$?

Comment: Yes but I cannot get the K and L in the denominator in the two fractions...

Comment: In response to the edit: you can just simplify by $K$ and $L$.

Comment: Yes I realised that... such a dumb mistake :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it was solved in the comments.